# CassandraIO didn't work for saving Timestamp

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-beam, dataflow

Here it is my simple code, it read from pubsub subscription and save the body of the message to Cassandra table with current timestamp.

The message is consumed from subscription but there is no record insert to table and there is no error messages.

But if I change Date type "Timestamp" to Long in class TestTable, this code is working and insert the record to the table.

here it is the script to create the table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table(
    post_index int,
    ingestion_time TIMESTAMP,
    body text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((post_index))
);
```

```
@Table(keyspace = "{keyspace_name}", name = "{table_name}",
        readConsistency = "LOCAL_QUORUM",
        writeConsistency = "LOCAL_QUORUM",
        caseSensitiveKeyspace = false,
        caseSensitiveTable = false)
class TestTable implements Serializable {
  @PartitionKey
  @Column(name="post_index")
  Integer postIndex;
  @Column(name="ingestion_time")
  Timestamp ingestionTime;
  @Column(name = "body")
  String body;

    public Integer getPostIndex() {
        return postIndex;
    }

    public void setPostIndex(Integer postIndex) {
        this.postIndex = postIndex;
    }

    public Timestamp getIngestionTime() {
        return ingestionTime;
    }

    public void setIngestionTime(Timestamp ingestionTime) {
        this.ingestionTime = ingestionTime;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public TestTable(Integer postIndex, Timestamp ingestionTime, String body) {
      this.body = body;
      this.ingestionTime = ingestionTime;
      this.postIndex = postIndex;
  }
  public TestTable() {
        this.body = "";
        this.ingestionTime = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
        this.postIndex = 0;
  }
}

public class TestCassandraJobJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).create());

       PCollection<String> data = pipeline.apply("ReadStrinsFromPubsub",
                PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription("projects/{project_id}/subscriptions/{subscription_name}"))
                .apply("window", Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(5))))
        .apply("CreateMutation", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, TestTable>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(@Element String word, OutputReceiver<TestTable> out) {
                TestTable t = new TestTable(new Random().nextInt(), java.sql.Timestamp.from(Instant.now()), word);
                out.output(t);
            }
        })).apply(CassandraIO.<TestTable>write()
                        .withHosts(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1"))
                        .withPort(9042)
                        .withKeyspace("{keyspace}")
                        .withLocalDc("Cassandra")
                        .withEntity(TestTable.class)
                );
        pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }
}
```

Comment: can we see an example of a message that you're trying to process?

Comment: what is the full class name for `Timestamp`?

Comment: message is very simple json {"body":"abc"}

Comment: The full class name of Timestamp is java.sql.Timestamp

Answer (score 0):

To get this working you need to have a codec between the Cassandra's `timestamp` and `java.sql.Timestamp`. By default, in Java driver 3.x, the `timestamp` is converted into `java.util.Date` (see [mapping](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping)), although you can also use Joda Time, or Java 8.x time API via [extra codecs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/custom_codecs/extras/).  And in Java driver 4.x, the `Instant` is used for representation of timestamps.

There is no built-in codec for `java.sql.Timestamp`, but it shouldn't be very hard to implement your own - the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/custom_codecs/) describes process of custom codec creation & usage in much details.